# Core Data iphone debugging pointers

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a reasonably complex Core Data app for the the iPhone.  For the most part, it's working well, but I'm running into a sporadic problem that manifests itself within Core Data.

I'm fetching data from a remote service, said service returns data.  I parse the data and modify various managed objects.  Then I save the managed object context and I get an error.  In the course of printing the error I get the following message:
*** -[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cd7aa0

I can isolate the problem down to a single setter in my one of my managed objects.  I save the managed object context before using the setting and I save the managed object context right after.  Failure happens right after.

This is all being done in the main thread.  I have more than one managed object context, but only one persistent store.

Any pointers for debugging this sort of Core Data problem are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular problem was caused by a method with the word "get" in it that corresponded to a field name in the managed object.  It, in turn, masked the real problem which is database related.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I crafted a workaround. **Subclass the `NSManagedObject` and manually transform the `UIImage` by overriding the accessor methods for the image property.**

- In the setter method, transform the `UIImage` object into an instance of `NSData`, and then set the managed object's image property.
- In the getter method, transform image property's data, and return an instance of `UIImage`.

Let's get to work:

In the data model, when you click the attribute, "image", delete the *Value Transformer Name*'s text. It defaults to *NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData*, which is what you now want.

Next, subclass the entity by clicking on it in the data model, click *New File*. When you have the entity selected, you should see a new class in *Cocoa Touch Classes* titled "Managed Object Class." Click *Next*, leave the file's location as is by clicking *Next* again, and then put a checkmark next to all the entities you want to subclass.

In the implementation file of your subclassed `NSManagedObject`, override the image property's accessor methods by including the following two:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"image"];

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [self setPrimitiveValue:data forKey:@"image"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"image"];
}

- (UIImage *)image {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"image"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self primitiveValueForKey:@"image"]];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"image"];
    return image;
}
```

Then, whenever you set the image, use:

```
object.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
```

rather than:

```
[object setValue:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] forKey:@"image"];
```

Whenever you get the image, use:

```
UIImage *myImage = object.image;
```

rather than:

```
UIImage *myImage = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
```